# How do i send the form parametrs of an html form via javascript Ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html form (see code below) with an ajax button. I would like to send the form parameters via AJAX post.

My problem is that I’m not sure how can I target the value of the HTML form fields (the value that the user inserted).

How do I send the HTML parameters via ajax post using JavaScript?

FYI: I do not want to use formData.

Here is the code:

```
<body>

    <form id="my-form-id" method="post" action="Calendar_form3.php">

        Year:<INPUT NAME="gregorian_year" SIZE=4 MAXLENGTH=4 value="2016">(1-6000)
        Latitude: <INPUT NAME="latitude" value="40.7127">
        Longitude: <INPUT NAME="longitude" value="-74.0059">
        <button id="ajax-button" type="button">Ajax button</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        function displayCalendar() {
            var divtarget = document.getElementById("main");


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('post', 'Calendar_form3.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState);
                if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                    divtarget.innerHTML = 'LOADING';
                }
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var text = xhr.responseText;

                    divtarget.innerHTML = text;
                }
            }
            xhr.send(gregorian_year=???&latitude=???&longitude=???);
        }

        var button = document.getElementById("ajax-button");
        button.addEventListener("click", displayCalendar);
    </script>

    <div id='main'>
        result here
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the code in page `Calendar_form3.php`:

```
<?php
echo "ajax working!!";
echo $_POST['gregorian_year'] . $_POST['latitude']. $_POST['longitude'];
?>
```

How can i complete this code line:

```
xhr.send(gregorian_year=???&latitude=???&longitude=???);
```

In other words, given my HTML form, how do I send the html parameters via AJAX post using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function displayCalendar() {
    var divtarget = document.getElementById("main");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Get Input Values
    var lon = document.getElementsByName('longitude')[0].value;
    var lat = document.getElementsByName('latitude')[0].value;
    var ger = document.getElementsByName('gregorian_year')[0].value;
//make the params string
    var params = "latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lon + "&gregorian_year=" + ger;
//Initialize as POST
    xhr.open("POST", 'Calendar_form3.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState);
        if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
            divtarget.innerHTML = 'LOADING';
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var text = xhr.responseText;
            divtarget.innerHTML = text;
        }
    }
//Send
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `getElementsByName()` DOM method to get the *gregorian_year*, *latitude* and *longitude* field values, like this:

```
var gregorian_year = document.getElementsByName("gregorian_year")[0].value;
var latitude = document.getElementsByName("latitude")[0].value;
var longitude = document.getElementsByName("longitude")[0].value;
```

And then use these variables in AJAX's `send()` method, like this:

```
xhr.send("gregorian_year="+gregorian_year+'&latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude);
```